# Comparing date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

Tags: php, time, conditional-statements

how can I make a conditional statement like if date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); is more than 30 seconds after date("Y-m-d h:i:s");.

I've previously used something like date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); < date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); + 30, however this doesn't seem to work.

Help?

Comment: @all, anyone have checked if we pass directly `if('2020-10-20 01:30:31'> '2020-10-20 01:35:32 '){ .. }` in PHP and then it works according like date comparing and gives proper result but I know that it is not the proper way or it is the wrong way. Then anyone can explain, in which case this will be not working with any example date and time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert them to [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

E.g.:

```
if(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1) > 30) {
    // $date2 is more than 30 seconds after $date1
}
```

or

```
if(abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)) > 30) {
    // $dates are more than 30 second apart
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtotime()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert both dates to a unix timestamp, then add the wanted amount of seconds to the second and do an integer comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use unixtime, instead. Just convert your date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); to date("U") or just time().
[strototime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) could help you with this.
 It shows the time in seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). Then this method $unixtime + 30 will work fine as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compare database date fields (like mysql `DATETIME`). Use the database systems date and time functions to compare date values (like `DATE_ADD()` or `+` and with simple `<` or `>` in MySQL).